# tensorflow earlystopping does not work properly

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm dealing with bunch of image dataset
However it takes a lot of time to learn, so I used earlystopping in tensorflow 
This is my callback option & fit option
(I know monitoring acc is not a good option, but just wanted to see how earlystopping works)

```
tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
  monitor='accuracy', 
  patience=3, 
  #mode='max',
  verbose=2, 
  baseline=0.98
)

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=16, epochs=10, verbose=2, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

However, this is the result:

```
101/101 - 42s - loss: 6.9557 - accuracy: 6.2461e-04 - val_loss: 6.9565 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10

101/101 - 39s - loss: 6.9549 - accuracy: 0.0019 - val_loss: 6.9558 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10

101/101 - 37s - loss: 6.9537 - accuracy: 0.0037 - val_loss: 6.9569 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 00003: early stopping
```

since monitoring value 'accuracy' kept increasing, expected it not to stop.
plus, I want earlystopping to monitor acc like this

```
acc=0, acc=0.1....acc=0.5, acc=0.4, acc=0.5, acc=0.6 #dont stop if increases again in patience epoch 

acc=0, acc=0.1....acc=0.5, acc=0.3, acc=0.4, acc=0.35 #stop if acc does not increases again in patience epoch
```

How should I do that?

Comment: So you want it to monitor the accuracy and to stop training if the accuracy does not increase for about 0.5 over 2 epochs?

Comment: minimum delta is 0.001. sorry.

Comment: and actually, 3epochs. if accuraccy does not increase minimum 0.001 over 3 epochs , i want this model to stop training

Comment: Training stops here because of the baseline parameter. As per the documentation ```Baseline value for the monitored quantity. Training will stop if the model doesn't show improvement over the baseline.```, you are basically saying that it starts at 98% accuracy and if it does not improve over the baseline value over 3 epochs stop training.

Comment: This should perform the way you expect :
```tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', min_delta=0.001,patience=3,mode='auto',verbose=2,baseline=None)```

Comment: i think you are right. thanks

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the use of `Baseline`

As per the documentation it is defined as :

```
Baseline value for the monitored quantity. Training will stop if the model doesn't show improvement over the baseline.
```

By setting Baseline to 98% you are stating that the model's accuracy starts at 98% and it it does not improve over the baseline over 3 epochs stop training.

Instead do the following as per your use case:

```
tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='accuracy', 
    min_delta=0.001,
    patience=3,
    mode='auto',
    verbose=2,
    baseline=None
)
```